# Kubernetes DNS fails in Kubernetes 1.2

Tags: dns, kubernetes, skydns

I'm attempting to set up DNS support in Kubernetes 1.2 on Centos 7.  According to the [documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/dns#how-do-i-configure-it), there's two ways to do this.  The first applies to a "supported kubernetes cluster setup" and involves setting environment variables:

```
ENABLE_CLUSTER_DNS="${KUBE_ENABLE_CLUSTER_DNS:-true}"
DNS_SERVER_IP="10.0.0.10"
DNS_DOMAIN="cluster.local"
DNS_REPLICAS=1
```

I added these settings to /etc/kubernetes/config and rebooted, with no effect, so either I don't have a supported kubernetes cluster setup (what's that?), or there's something else required to set its environment.

The second approach requires more manual setup.  It adds two flags to kubelets, which I set by updating /etc/kubernetes/kubelet to include:

```
KUBELET_ARGS="--cluster-dns=10.0.0.10 --cluster-domain=cluster.local"
```

and restarting the kubelet with `systemctl restart kubelet`.  Then it's necessary to start a replication controller and a service.  The doc page cited above provides a couple of template files for this that require some editing, both for local changes (my Kubernetes API server listens to the actual IP address of the hostname rather than 127.0.0.1, making it necessary to add a --kube-master-url setting) and to remove some Salt dependencies.  When I do this, the replication controller starts four containers successfully, but the kube2sky container gets terminated about a minute after completing initialization:

```
[david@centos dns]$ kubectl --server="http://centos:8080" --namespace="kube-system" logs -f kube-dns-v11-t7nlb -c kube2sky
I0325 20:58:18.516905       1 kube2sky.go:462] Etcd server found: http://127.0.0.1:4001
I0325 20:58:19.518337       1 kube2sky.go:529] Using http://192.168.87.159:8080 for kubernetes master
I0325 20:58:19.518364       1 kube2sky.go:530] Using kubernetes API v1
I0325 20:58:19.518468       1 kube2sky.go:598] Waiting for service: default/kubernetes
I0325 20:58:19.533597       1 kube2sky.go:660] Successfully added DNS record for Kubernetes service.
F0325 20:59:25.698507       1 kube2sky.go:625] Received signal terminated
```

I've determined that the termination is done by the healthz container after reporting:

```
2016/03/25 21:00:35 Client ip 172.17.42.1:58939 requesting /healthz probe servicing cmd nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local 127.0.0.1 >/dev/null
2016/03/25 21:00:35 Healthz probe error: Result of last exec: nslookup: can't resolve 'kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local', at 2016-03-25 21:00:35.608106622 +0000 UTC, error exit status 1
```

Aside from this, all other logs look normal.  However, there is one anomaly: it was necessary to specify --validate=false when creating the replication controller, as the command otherwise gets the message:

```
error validating "skydns-rc.yaml": error validating data: [found invalid field successThreshold for v1.Probe, found invalid field failureThreshold for v1.Probe]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

Could this be related?  These arguments come directly Kubernetes documentation.  if not, what's needed to get this running?

Here is the skydns-rc.yaml I used:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: kube-dns-v11
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: kube-dns
    version: v11
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    k8s-app: kube-dns
    version: v11
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: kube-dns
        version: v11
        kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: etcd
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/etcd-amd64:2.2.1
        resources:
          # TODO: Set memory limits when we've profiled the container for large
          # clusters, then set request = limit to keep this container in
          # guaranteed class. Currently, this container falls into the
          # "burstable" category so the kubelet doesn't backoff from restarting it.
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 500Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 50Mi
        command:
        - /usr/local/bin/etcd
        - -data-dir
        - /var/etcd/data
        - -listen-client-urls
        - http://127.0.0.1:2379,http://127.0.0.1:4001
        - -advertise-client-urls
        - http://127.0.0.1:2379,http://127.0.0.1:4001
        - -initial-cluster-token
        - skydns-etcd
        volumeMounts:
        - name: etcd-storage
          mountPath: /var/etcd/data
      - name: kube2sky
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/kube2sky:1.14
        resources:
          # TODO: Set memory limits when we've profiled the container for large
          # clusters, then set request = limit to keep this container in
          # guaranteed class. Currently, this container falls into the
          # "burstable" category so the kubelet doesn't backoff from restarting it.
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            # Kube2sky watches all pods.
            memory: 200Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 50Mi
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          timeoutSeconds: 5
          successThreshold: 1
          failureThreshold: 5
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /readiness
            port: 8081
            scheme: HTTP
          # we poll on pod startup for the Kubernetes master service and
          # only setup the /readiness HTTP server once that's available.
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        args:
        # command = "/kube2sky"
        - --domain="cluster.local"
        - --kube-master-url=http://192.168.87.159:8080
      - name: skydns
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/skydns:2015-10-13-8c72f8c
        resources:
          # TODO: Set memory limits when we've profiled the container for large
          # clusters, then set request = limit to keep this container in
          # guaranteed class. Currently, this container falls into the
          # "burstable" category so the kubelet doesn't backoff from restarting it.
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 50Mi
        args:
        # command = "/skydns"
        - -machines=http://127.0.0.1:4001
        - -addr=0.0.0.0:53
        - -ns-rotate=false
        - -domain="cluster.local"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 53
          name: dns
          protocol: UDP
        - containerPort: 53
          name: dns-tcp
          protocol: TCP
      - name: healthz
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/exechealthz:1.0
        resources:
          # keep request = limit to keep this container in guaranteed class
          limits:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 20Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 20Mi
        args:
        - -cmd=nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local 127.0.0.1 >/dev/null
        - -port=8080
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
      volumes:
      - name: etcd-storage
        emptyDir: {}
      dnsPolicy: Default  # Don't use cluster DNS.
```

and skydns-svc.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kube-dns
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: kube-dns
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    kubernetes.io/name: "KubeDNS"
spec:
  selector:
    k8s-app: kube-dns
  clusterIP:  "10.0.0.10"
  ports:
  - name: dns
    port: 53
    protocol: UDP
  - name: dns-tcp
    port: 53
    protocol: TCP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just commented out the lines that contain the `successThreshold` and `failureThreshold` values in `skydns-rc.yaml`, then re-run the kubectl commands.

```
kubectl create -f skydns-rc.yaml
kubectl create -f skydns-svc.yaml
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, it made no difference.

Comment: What's the value of SERVICE_CLUSTER_IP_RANGE? Make sure your DNS IP is in the same network as the value you specify there.

Comment: This was the problem!  Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem. where do I find SERVICE_CLUSTER_IP_RANGE? and what do I set it to if I am running on a local ubuntu machine?

Comment: Look in `cluster/ubuntu/config-default.sh`. If your Ubuntu machine has a typical 192.168.1.0/24 network, set the value of `SERVICE_CLUSTER_IP_RANGE` to 192.168.254.0/24 or something similar that doesn't overlap your main network. Then pick the value of `DNS_SERVER_IP` to be in that range, 192.168.254.10.