# How to install Kubernetes from release binary

Tags: linux, centos, installation, kubernetes

I'm trying to run Kubernetes on a local Centos server and have had some issues (for example, [with DNS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36228065/kubernetes-dns-fails-in-kubernetes-1-2)).  A version check shows that I'm running Kubernetes 1.2 Alpha 1.  Since the full release is now available from the [Releases Download](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/releases) page, I'd like to upgrade and see if that resolves my issue.  The [documentation](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/binary_release/) for installing a prebuilt binary release states:

*Download the latest release and unpack this tar file on Linux or OS X, cd to the created kubernetes/ directory, and then follow the getting started guide for your cloud.*

However, the [Getting Started Guide for Centos](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/centos/centos_manual_config/) says nothing about using a prebuilt binary.  Instead, it tells you to set up a yum repo and run a yum install command:

```
yum -y install --enablerepo=virt7-docker-common-release kubernetes
```

This command downloads and installs the Alpha1 release.  In addition, it attempts to install Docker 1.8 (two releases down from the current 1.10), which fails if Docker is already installed.

How can I install from a prebuilt binary and use an existing Docker?

Comment: regarding DNS issues in Kubernetes, you might want to read this thread: 
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/8042#issuecomment-202754514
IMO better to try to fix DNS than go with an alpha version...

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Table of Solutions](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/#table-of-solutions) for installing Kubernetes, the maintainer of the CentOS getting started guide is [@coolsvap](https://github.com/coolsvap). You should reach out to him to ask about getting the pre-built binary updated to the official release.